# How to get Anonym Objects parameters?

Tags: java, hashtable, anonymous-objects

Im trying to add my anonymous objects from a class to a Hashtable. I created my Hashtable as my teacher wants but there is one problem. I have to get x and y values one of my Objects. But System cannot find x anyway.

```
public class HashDatastructure{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    java.util.Hashtable kreise = new java.util.Hashtable();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      kreise.put(new Integer(i), new Kreis(120, 120, 60));
    }
    System.out.println(kreise.get(3).toString() + " is 4. Object
                       and this Object's X Value: "
                     + kreise.get(3).x + " || Y Value: ");
  }
}
```

And here it is my Kreis Class:

```
public class Kreis extends Object{
    public int x; //Mittelpunkt-x
    public int y; // Mittelpunkt-y
    public int radius;
    public final double PI = 3.14159; //Constant Variable for pi
    public static int kreisCounter = kreisZaehler();
    public static int counter = 0;


    public Kreis(int x, int y, int radius){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.radius = radius;
      kreisCounter();
    }

    private static int kreisZaehler(){
      counter++;
      return counter;
    }
    public void setRadius(int wert){
      radius = wert;
    }

    public double getFlaeche(){
      return radius * radius * PI;
    }

    public double getUmfang(){
      return 2 * radius * PI;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A few things, you might want to write your code in english, it makes it easier to follow for those of us that does not speak German(?). Secondly, and this is important: INCLUDE THE ERROR YOU GET. The actual problem here is too vague. And a last note, you try to do `kreise.get(3).x` but `x` in `Kreis` is set to private. Either change this to public, or create a getter method.

Comment: Thank you for you kind Feedback @OptimusCrime .Next time I'll be more carefull about these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "anonymous objects," but you're using *raw types*, which is generally not a good idea. Instead, tell the compiler what kind of object `kreis` contains:

```
java.util.Hashtable<Kreise> kreise = new java.util.Hashtable<>();
// ----------------^^^^^^^^---------------------------------^^
```

Then, the compiler will know that `get` returns a `Kreis` object, which has `x` and such. (Side note: Probably better to make `x` private and provide an accessor like `getX` for it.)

More to explore in the [Generics Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

If for some reason you *have* to use raw types, you can cast to `Kreis` on retrieval:

```
// NOT recommended
System.out.println(kreise.get(3).toString() + " is 4. Object and this Object's X Value: "
                 + (((Kreise)kreise.get(3)).getX() + " || Y Value: ");
// -----------------^^^^^^^^^-------------^-^^^^^^
```

(Note I'm assuming you make `x` private and provide an accessor for it.)

Comment: I don't know but somehow book wants from me the not recommended way. But it works that way. Thank you.

Comment: @HürkanDoğan - The book is also using `Hashtable`, which has **long** been obsolete. I think probably the book you're using is extremely old (in software terms). You'd probably be better off using a newer book or online courses.